# How to avoid Concurrency from front end

Tags: java, javascript, oracle11g

We have a requirement where manager log in to site and see list of user record in table format. when he click on certain record he get detail of user and call user to resolve his issue.Now It is possible that two manager login and click on same record and call the same user at same time. We want to avoid this.

Condition 1: Two manager login at same time record is available to both in normal color say green. Manager 1 click on record and start editing/calling user. In this case there should be some kind of lock so that if manager 2 tries to open same record he will get pop up message 'In progress'.

Condition 2: Manager 1 login and see record in green color. Then Manager 2 login and see same record in grey color. Now he should not be able to click that record.

---

Manager1: select status, ver_no from record where record_id=? (ver_no is now zero)
Click on record to see the detail and 
update record set status='In progress', ver_no=1 where record_id=? and ver_no=0 (ver_no is now 1 - Success)

Now manager two login after some time and manager 1 has not closed the record means status is still in progress or he closed browser directly
Manager2: select status, ver_no from record where record_id=? (ver_no is now 1)
Click on record to see the detail and 
Manager2: update record set status='In progress', ver_no=1 where record_id=? and ver_no=1 (ver_no is now 1 - Success)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good case for an optimistic locking scenario. This will only work in the backend server code. You cannot lock the user using java script on the front end.

Let me explain in simple terms how to do this:

Add a version number column and a status flag to a database table. Probably on the record table.

Manager 1 clicks on record, select the record from the database first, increment the version number and update the flag saying the record is now picked up.

Manager 2 clicks on the record, (if he does so at the same Manager 2 will select the same record as selected by Manager 1). But when Manager 2 tries to update the record, the version number will not match up and the update will return back with no rows updated. Use this to update your UI saying the record is in progress.

The conversation will be like the below:

```
Manager1: select status, ver_no from record where record_id=? (ver_no is now zero)
Manager2: select status, ver_no from record where record_id=? (ver_no is now zero)

Manager1: update record set status='In progress', ver_no=1 where record_id=? and ver_no=0 (ver_no is now 1 - Success)
Manager2: update record set status='In progress', ver_no=1 where record_id=? and ver_no=0 (This will fail to update any row)
```

The above is only in case they both attack the same row at the same time. Most of the time when Manager 2 selects itself, the status will already be In progress. If not you can work with that record.

Comment: Thanks Sethu for your reply. but i have one issue here the record will be lost if manager select record and without calling the user directly close the browser.

Comment: MM.. don't think there is an easy way of doing this. One way that comes to my mind, is having a record of who is logged in to the system. Make sure that table gets updated when the session timesout or the user logs out manually. Next have a time limit as to how long the record can stay In Progress. If the record is in Progress too long and the user has logged out, then bump out manager 1 and assign it to manager 2.

Comment: What if Manger-1 opens up the edit window and never saves his updates.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply keep a flag in the database. when the button is clicked it will be set as a false and when operation finishes set it back to true. So the other user's access gets restricted.

Comment: I have issue here the record will be lost if manager select record and without calling the user directly close the browser.

Comment: That is very different question and should probably be asked separately